# How to subscribe to a AnimationController on RealityKit

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, visionos

The following code moves an entity throughout the space when tapped. That works fine but how would I get an event notification (I imagine a AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted)for when the animation finishes?

```
struct ImmersiveGameView: View {
    let entity = Utils.generateBall(color: .green) //Generates a Entity sphere
    let viewModel = ImmersiveGameViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            entity.setPosition(SIMD3(0, 1, -0.7), relativeTo: nil)
            content.add(entity)
        }

        .gesture(SpatialTapGesture().targetedToAnyEntity().onEnded({ value in
            var transform = Transform()
            transform.translation.z = entity.position.z - 10
            transform.translation.x = entity.position.x
            transform.translation.y = entity.position.y
            value.entity.move(to: transform, relativeTo: nil, duration: 2)
        }))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On visionOS, use the `subscribe(to:on:)` instance method if you want to subscribe to AnimationEvents.

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.1))
    @State var subscriptions: [EventSubscription] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            entity.position = [0, 1,-2]
            entity.components[InputTargetComponent.self] = .init()
            entity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: false)

            let es = content.subscribe(to: AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted.self, 
                                       on: entity) { e in
                Task {
                    print(e.playbackController.isPlaying)               // false
                    print(e.playbackController.isComplete)              // true
                    print((e.playbackController.entity?.position.z)!)   // -7.0
                }
            }
            subscriptions.append(es)
            content.add(entity)
        }
        .gesture(
            SpatialTapGesture()
                .targetedToEntity(entity)
                .onEnded { _ in
                    var transform = Transform()
                    transform.translation.z = entity.position.z - 5.0
                    transform.translation.y = entity.position.y
                    entity.move(to: transform, relativeTo: nil, 
                          duration: 0.5, timingFunction: .linear)
                    
                }
        )
    }
}
```